# Idiomatic ways to handle errors in JAX jitted functions

Tags: python, jax

As the title states, I'd like to know what idiomatic methods are available to raise exceptions or handle errors in JAX jitted functions. The functional nature of JAX makes it unclear how to accomplish this.

The closest official documentation I could find is the [`jax.experimental.checkify`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jax.experimental.checkify.html) module, but this wasn't very clear and seemed incomplete.

This [Github comment](https://github.com/google/jax/issues/4257#issuecomment-1276298349) claims that Python exceptions can be raised by using `jax.debug.callback()` and `jax.lax.cond()` functions. I attempted to do this, but an error is thrown during compilation. A minimum working example is below:

```
import jax
from jax import jit

def _raise(ex):
    raise ex


@jit
def error_if_positive(x):
    jax.lax.cond(
        x > 0,
        lambda : jax.debug.callback(_raise, ValueError("x is positive")),
        lambda : None,
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":

    error_if_positive(-1)
```

The abbreviated error statement:

```
TypeError: Value ValueError('x is positive') with type <class 'ValueError'> is not a valid JAX type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use callbacks to raise errors, for example:

```py
import jax
from jax import jit

def _raise_if_positive(x):
  if x > 0:
    raise ValueError("x is positive")

@jit
def error_if_positive(x):
  jax.debug.callback(_raise_if_positive, x)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  error_if_positive(-1)  # no error
  error_if_positive(1)
  # XlaRuntimeError: INTERNAL: Generated function failed: CpuCallback error: ValueError: x is positive
```

The reason your approach didn't work is becuase your error is raised at trace-time rather than at runtime, and both branches of the `cond` will always be traced.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Is there any kind of runtime penalty for performing the check inside the callback? Like bounds checking array indices for example?

Comment: Yes, callbacks generally incur runtime penalties: for example, if you perform a callback on the result of a sub-computation, it might prevent the compiler from fusing that with a subsequent computation. I would not recommend using callbacks in performance-critical code.